# Input lines of data as arguments in python

Tags: python, linux, database, apache-nifi, dataflow

I want to transfer data from source to destination using `NI-FI`.In `NI-FI` I also want to use a python script to mask my Data.so someone suggests me that pass one by one input lines of data as arguments in python.

So I want to know that i need to pass the file or each row and column manually in my python script for masking. what is the best approach and how can i get it.

In NI-FI i also want to use a python script to mask my Data, but Getfile  Processor and python script pointing out the same file which is located in Input folder of NI-FI, so may be due to this reason I am getting an error in Execute stream command.

Below script as requested by user @GMc :-

```
   class ModJSON(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        flowFile = session.get()
        obj = {
            "Source": "NiFi",
            "IP": obj['IP'].replace(regex='((?<=[0-9])[0-9]|(?<=\.)[0-9])', value='X'),
            "Name": obj['user']['screen_name']
        }
```

In this script I want to mask my data which is coming from GetFile processor but file is in queue.

I want to get data from the source and transform this.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a little while, but if I remember correctly, NiFi's interface to python provides you with a global variable called session.

You use the session object to get the flow file and transfer your output down the correct downstream path (e.g. Success).

Perhaps this tutorial will help you https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/35568/python-script-in-nifi.html

I'm a bit confused about your reference to GetInputFile (do you mean GetFile processor?) and the python script. Normally the GetFile obtains a file from the file system. This is then converted to an internal mechanism within NiFi known as a FlowFile. Downstream processors (e.g. python scripts) get the flow File from the session object do something with it and optionally transfer the modified version via the session.transfer method.

Comment: Yes it is GetFile processor.
And i tried using your method but i am getting anouther error which is "Can't take value of a macro (clojure)"
can you assist me for this also

Comment: You need to provide a bit more detail. For example, are you trying to provide a clojure script, or are you still trying to work on python, but forgot to select "pyton" in the "script engine" drop down in the execute script processor. Something else???

Comment: yes i am still working on python and now select python from 'Script Engine' but my nifi programme is still running from last 1 hour and file is in queue.

i want to know that for python script 'executeStreamCommand' or 'Eexecutescript' which processor is more preferable. becuse i need to you Pandas and Json in my script

Comment: Again, it has been a while, but if memory serves ExecuteScript provides you with a session object which allows you to integrate with NiFi (e.g. select a transfer path, access flow file and possibly more). Whereas ExecuteStreamCommand does not. The flow file is provided via standard input. Whichever you choose, as long as you get the flow file correctly, you can then process the contents using whatever capabilities (e.g. JSON parsing) that are available to you.

Comment: Right now i am using ExecuteScript and in this processor i write python script using session object but my flow iskeep running from a long time without any error or any output and my file is still in queue. you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Not without seeing the script. SOme common problems might be: It is waiting for something to be input from the console (i.e. you are maybe reading from standard input). Another common problem is not transferring the flowfile to an output (e.g. success) - although this probably will generate an error. Another possible problem is an infinite loop or a very very long running loop that looks like it never ends. I suggest replacing the NiFi parts of your script (e.g. getFlowFile) with an open of a text file and running it outside of NiFi to debug any issues with the script itself.

Comment: class ModJSON(StreamCallback):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        flowFile = session.get()
        obj = {
            "Source": "NiFi",
            "IP": obj['IP'].replace(regex='((?<=[0-9])[0-9]|(?<=\.)[0-9])', value='X'),
            "Name": obj['user']['screen_name']
        }

in this script i want to mask my data which is coming from GetFile processor but file isin queue.

Comment: Thanks for sending that, but can you put this in your question as a code block? it is almost impossible to read as a comment. You can create a code block by using three back ticks refer to [Markdown Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You can edit the question by clicking the edit link at the bottom of the question. If you want people to help you, you need to make it easy for them to do so. My reason for saying this is that I might not know how to answer the question, but someone else will. However, they probably won't have time to read through all this to get the whole question.

Comment: Thanks @GMc, i  had updated the code in question section. now you can check & assist me

Comment: can you asst me further about this, i tried using session object also in my script but my program is still in running phase.